# Lef $f$ be a module homomorphism , $f$ is one-one if and only if $\ker f={0}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am following Herstein's Topics in Algebra and according to that book a module may be defined on a ring without 1 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMeIZ.png).

So if we consider a module $M$ over a ring $R$ without $1$, then will be the statement in the question true ? If yes , then how to prove it ?

Comment: You don't need 1 in your ring in the standard proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prove it exactly as in the case of modules over rings with unity.

In order to show the equivalence between injectivity of a map and triviality of the kernel you only use the fact that
$$
f(x-y)=f(x)-f(y).
$$
Mind that you still have $-y$ and $f(-y)=-f(y)$ even though you don't have $1$ (and so $-1$) because a module is nonetheless an *additive* group.

Comment: All the answers were nice , but "Mind that you still have −y and f(−y)=−f(y) even though you don't have 1 (and so −1) because a module is nonetheless an additive group." solved my doubt and hence i accept it .(But i upvoted all other answers)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that$Ker f=0$, $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $f(x-y)=0$ and $x-y\in Ker f$ we deduce that $x-y=0$ and $x=y$.

$f$ is one to one, $f(x)=0=f(0)$ implies $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is one-to-one, then for any $x,y$ (elements of module)
$$
f(x)=f(y) \Leftrightarrow x=y
$$
$$
0 = f(x) - f(y) = f(x-y) \Leftrightarrow x = y
$$
So $x-y$ is in the kernel of $f$ if and only if $x-y=0$. Hope you can work out the rest of the proof.